# Samsung s3 neo contact

Tags: contacts

In my contact list when I access it I see the person name along with details of list in which it is listed like Google contact & WhatsApp etc. Is there a way that I can download contact in excel along with info about listing I. E. Google or WhatsApp etc?

Answer (score 0):

Download [Contacts backup excel and email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eastros.c2x) and run the app. It will backup all your contacts along with all their info stored I.E:addresses, emails, Google+ profiles. It won't however backup WhatsApp profile data. This is because that data is not contact data but rather data that belongs to the WhatsApp application.